# Specifying rules in the Linkextractors in scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

Is there a format to specify the rules in the `LinkExtractor` in scrapy? I have read the documentation but it was not very clear to me. In my case the url links values keep increasing after the first page (something like &pg=2 and so on). For example see below:

```
start_urls = ['http://www.examples.com']
rules= [Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=['www.examples.com/sports/companies?searchTerm=news+sports&pg=2']), 'parse_torrent')]
```

Let me know if there is a right way to specify the url in rules so that I can scrape page 1, page 2...page 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract links from your starting page. (for your case is http://www.examples.com)

You should create a spider inheriting from `CrawlSpider`, and use following regular expression.

```
rules = (
   Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'www.examples.com/sports/companies?searchTerm=news+sports&pg=\d+'], callback='parse_torrent'),
)
```

But seems like you already know your url rules, I would suggest you to generate url by yourself.

```
from scrapy.http.request import Request

def start_requests(self):
    for i in xrange(1, 100):
        url = 'www.examples.com/sports/companies?searchTerm=news+sports&pg=' + i
        yield Request(url=url, callback=parse_torrent)
```

Comment: Can you specify the regular expression using the Linkextractor? It seems the sgml is outdated and i am getting some error.

Comment: sorry, I will modify my code. Actually you can simply replace SgmlLinkExtractor to LinkExtractor

Answer (score 0):

allow is a regex, you are just pasting a full url which makes no sense.

> allow (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular expression (or list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) urls must match in order to be extracted. If not given (or empty), it will match all links.

[Source](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml)

It looks clear to me.